# Why Machenize package in Python opens the support page when I try to open Google AdWords?

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, web-scraping, google-ads-api

I use Machenize to open the google AdWord page, but it redirects to support page, please see the codes below.:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)  
br.set_handle_refresh(False)  

url="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin"
br.open(url)
br.form = list(br.forms())[0]

email = "myEmail"
password = "myPassword"

br.form["Email"] = email 
br.form["Passwd"] = password

response=br.submit() # And submit ! so far its ok, now Im in right page

br.open("https://adwords.google.com/") # The problem is here, the browser doesnt open this page
print br.geturl() # It opens this page : https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1704376?hl=en#browsersupport
```

there is no way I get in AdWords page, after login, I only end up with support page, why>
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdWords redirects to this support page when using a browser that is not supported.

You should be able to fix this by faking your user agent.

Comment: Thank you very much @Florianlh. You are right, after faking the agent using the following code, it works perfectly:


opener.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11'),
                     ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'),
                     ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate,sdch'),                  
                     ('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.8'),                     
                     ('Accept-Charset', 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3')]
]

Comment: Okay, I'm glad to see that solved your problem.

Could you mark my answer as accepted, then?